# Highcharts: VU meter text label behind needle

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am unable to get the text label above the VU meter needle.
The text label is now partly hidden underneeth the needle.
Example: http://postimage.org/image/sskyqrndh/
Code: http://pastebin.com/DmMV6A63

Does somebody know how i can push the label text above the needle?
I tried yaxis.margin, yaxis.offset etc, but they dont seem to move the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the yaxis label using the yaxis title `y` option:

```
title: {
  text: 'Some Text',
  align: 'middle',
  y: -110 // adjust this
}
```

This produces:

[image]

Example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aSvFB/).

Comment: i actually want the text to be in the same place, but not behind the needle. Just above it.

Comment: @HyperDevil, please don't feel compelled to accept my answer if it doesn't fit your needs.  After I got your comment, I actually tried a bunch of things to bring the text to front, but was unsuccessful.